# CSS Button with special clipped corners

Tags: css

[image]

This is an image. But I would like to do same with CSS. It is very easy to do normal button with CSS but not this button. Is it possible to do same corners in CSS?

Comment: You can create triangle using borders in CSS.  You should be able to google.   This depends on HTML you are working with.  Is it a link or actual button?

Comment: Look into pseudo-selectors ::before and ::after. Also, look into how to make triangles in css. Once you’ve tried something with those, if you get stuck, post that code back here and then somebody can help you with whatever you may be missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  height:200px; width: 100%;
  padding:50px;
}



.custom-button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #29aa4c;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
}

.custom-button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid black;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}

.custom-button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 20px solid black;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="custom-button">
    Sign In
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: that's a lot of code ... check this : https://jsfiddle.net/0x6s23f4/4/